# Announcing a Pro Tempore election

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Astronomy Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for a [special election](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **March 29** to bring in one more moderator.

For full details of the process, see the announcement on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections).

The timeline is as follows:

- Starting on March 29, users can [nominate themselves](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the `discussion` and `election` tags.)
- On April 5, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election.  If not, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-moderator-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-pa), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on April 12.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: Is there a list of expectations for moderators somewhere?  Like how often they are expected to log on to clear queues, etc?

Comment: @ConnorGarcia The general expectations are described here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/

Comment: @ConnorGarcia This is a great question though, because Astronomy has unique needs. Astronomy users tend to generate a lot more flags than similar sites (such as Space Exploration), so it would be most helpful to have someone who could be on regularly to help with the flag burn-down.

Comment: @ConnorGarcia Congrats on joining the mod team! I look forward to working with you.

Comment: @called2voyage Thanks very much.  I look forward to working with you as well.  Looks like I have some homework to do on learning policy and procedure tonight!